# importing data into CSV from a remote oracle server, I need to use a spool like command in Windows

Tags: windows, oracle, csv, batch-file

I need to write a similar script in windows in a bat/cmd file. This script gets my data in csv on linux. I was wondering if there is any equivalent in windows box.

```
FILE="test.csv"

sqlplus username/passwd@database <<EOF

SET PAGESIZE 50000
SET COLSEP ","
SET LINESIZE 200
SET FEEDBACK OFF

SPOOL $FILE

SELECT * FROM test_table ;

SPOOL OFF
EXIT
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the redirection operator!

```
FILE="test.csv"

sqlplus username/passwd@database <<EOF >> %FILE%

SET PAGESIZE 50000
SET COLSEP ","
SET LINESIZE 200
SET FEEDBACK OFF


SELECT * FROM test_table ;

EXIT
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use same commands in windows also, only thing you need is Oracle Client installed on the windows client machine, if it is a server then its ok. Create a .bat file and copy following script into it. Run the file from command prompt or double click, and csv file is created if database connection is successful and the table exits.

```
@echo off
sqlplus username/passwd@database

SET PAGESIZE 50000
SET COLSEP ","
SET LINESIZE 200
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET TRIMSPOOL OFF

SPOOL test.csv

SELECT * FROM test_table ;

SPOOL OFF
EXIT
```